# ImproperlyConfigured DeletePost's select_related property

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to enable the currently logged in user to delete their own post on my site. I'm using a DeleteView with select_related mixing. I keep getting an error that says it's improperly configured and needs to be a tuple or a list. Here is the error, my post models, and views. Not really sure where to go from here, and this doesn't seem to be a very popular error as I'm not really able to find much with a Google search.

Error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /colorsets/delete/7/
DeletePost's select_related property must be a tuple or list.
```

App Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from colorsets.forms import ColorForm
from colorsets import models
from colorsets.models import ColorSet
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
#def index(request):
#   return render(request,'index.html')

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = ColorSet

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ColorSet.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')

class CreateColorSetView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = ColorForm
    model = ColorSet

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,DeleteView):
    model = models.ColorSet
    select_related = ('user')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request,'Post Deleted')
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

App models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class ColorSet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='colorset')
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    color_one = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='cccccc')
    color_two = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='ffffff')
    color_three = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='e5e5e5')
    color_four = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='f0f0f0')
    color_five = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='bababa')

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Traceback:
[image]

Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the comma to make `select_related` a tuple.

```
select_related = ('user',)
```

Without the comma, `('user')` is the string `'user'`.

Comment: That worked thanks. So whats the difference between comma and no comma?

Comment: As I said, `('user')` without a comma is the string `'user'`, whereas `('user',)` with a comma is a tuple.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that you said that before. My bad, thanks for the help, although of course now I have another error lol.